# What's the fastest/simplest way to calculate a moving Average in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I can think on some dirty ways to calculate a moving average on Kotlin, but I'm not sure which one is the best. I know that kotlin has a lot of interesting features to work with collections and list. What do you think is the most efficient (or  simplest) way to calculate a moving average?

Comment: I guess `list.average()` is not the thing you wanted to hear. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: That's not a moving average.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Kotlin 1.2 will introduce a [sliding window](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/window-sliding.md) which you can combine with `average` obviously.

```
val data = listOf(1,2,5,6,2,7,8,5,9)
// 3 "period" moving average
val movingAverage = data.windowed(3,1,List<Int>::average)
// OR
val movingAverage = data.windowed(3,1) { it.average() }
```

Until then you would have to introduce your own sliding sequence.

```
class SlidingSequence<out T>(val source: Iterable<T>,
                                      val slideSize: Int,
                                      val slideStep: Int) : Sequence<List<T>> {
    override fun iterator(): Iterator<List<T>> = object : AbstractIterator<List<T>>() {
        private val iterator = if (slideSize > 0) source.iterator() else emptyList<T>().iterator()
        private var buffer = listOf<T>()

        override fun computeNext() = when {
            iterator.hasNext() -> {
                buffer = buffer.drop(slideStep).let {
                    it + iterator.asSequence().take(slideSize - it.size)
                }
                setNext(buffer)
            }
            else -> done()
        }
    }
}

fun <T> Iterable<T>.windowed(size: Int,
                          step: Int = 1): Sequence<List<T>> {
    return SlidingSequence(this, size, step)
}

// and then you can do
val data = listOf(1,2,5,6,2,7,8,5,9)
// 3 "period" moving average
val movingAverage = data.windowed(3).map(List<Int>::average)
```

PS. I haven't looked at the code of Kotlin 1.2 `windowed` implementation, but since the function takes an immediate transform, I'm guessing the result is not lazy, where in the self implemented case above it's a lazy result, so you need to actually enumerate the sequence with something like `.toList()` to get the actual values.

Comment: `Sequence.windowed` is lazy both with and without immediate transform.

Comment: @Ilya nice one!

Answer (score 0):

Another one-line given `period > 0` is:

`data?.takeLast(period)?.reduce { v, d ->  v + d}?: 0 / period`

This also works if the data is empty or null due to `takeLast()` `s behaviour.